# Errors in onCreateOptionsMenu in navigation search bar

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I’m using Kotlin for a navigation search bar.

So, when I click a button from MainActivity it opens a new activity that enable a simple search can be found.

I’m really struggling as I have a number of errors in the code (I'm a newbe so please be gentle on me!).

The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv_listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvemptyTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="No result"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The search code (I've shown the errors within the code:

```
    class SearchActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<*>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d("TAG", "SearchActivity 1 JEZ")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.search_main)

        adapter = ArrayAdapter(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            resources.getStringArray(R.array.vegetables)
        )

        lv_listView.adapter = adapter
        lv_listView.onItemClickListener =
            AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                Toast.makeText(
                    applicationContext,
                    parent?.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        lv_listView.emptyView = tvemptyTextView
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_menu,menu)   /* ERROR: Unresolved reference: menu */

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)

        val search: MenuItem? = menu?.findItem(R.id.nav_search) /* Unresolved reference: nav_search */
        val searchView: SearchView = search?.actionView as SearchView
        searchView.queryHint = "search something"

        /* Plus a number of errors in this section (which I think maybe related to the earlier problem?)ln assuming : object is not abstract.../Conflicting overload.../ */
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                return false
            }

            override fun onQueryTextSubmit(newText: String?): Boolean {
                adapter.filter.filter(newText)
                return true
            }
        })

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
}
```

If I've missed any bits out then I'll add in.

As I've been struggling on this for a few days now, so any help would be great! Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick tip - you can put the cursor on an error and do `Alt+Enter` to get some suggestions and automatic quick fixes, and also information about the error. Sometimes it can explain or fix the issue

Ok, so

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.nav_menu,menu)   /* ERROR: Unresolved reference: menu */
```

I had to paste this into Android Studio to see which `menu` was highlighted as the unrecognised one - it's the `R.`**`menu`**`.nav_menu` one. That means you don't have any `menu` resources yet, i.e. you don't have a `menu` XML file in a `menu` folder in your `res` folder.

So I'm guessing you haven't actually created `nav_menu.xml` yet. If you open the Project panel (or Alt+1) and in the Android view, find your `res` folder, right-click it and do `New > Android Resource File`. Under `Resource type` select `menu` and call it `nav_menu` and it should fix your first error, because now the file exists and gets added to your resources (the `R` stuff).

```
/* Unresolved reference: nav_search */
```

That'll be the same problem - there's nothing with a `nav_search` ID, so it doesn't recognise that name in your ID list in `R`. If you didn't create the menu, then you haven't created the menu item with that ID yet right?

---

```
object is not abstract.../Conflicting overload...
```

Two problems here, but caused by the same thing - the longer error message tells you that the object isn't abstract, so there's an abstract method you **need** to implement, which you haven't yet.

The "conflicting overload" message tells you you have the same method (same name, same parameter types and order, same return type) already implemented.

Basically you have two methods you need to implement, but you've given them the same name - one should be `onQueryTextSubmit` and the other is `onQueryTextChange`. They have the right parameter names so the bottom one must have got renamed at some point. Change it to... `change` and that'll clear up both issues

---

Also your entire bottom half of that `onOptionsMenuCreated` method should be highlighted in a warning colour, and if you hover over it it should say "unreachable code". That's because the line before that unreachable code block starts is a `return` statement, it exits the method there. So that needs to go! And the real `return` statement (the one at the end) [needs to return `true`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu))

> You must return true for the menu to be displayed; if you return false it will not be shown.

Comment: That is brilliant! Really appreciate the help and I've made some great progress! THANK YOU!